# How to access a UI object from another thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an activity which have ListView. When I want to access this ListView from another thread I got this error ..

How may I do that ?

Error Log :

```
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewRoot.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRoot.java:1712)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:452)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:452)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:452)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:452)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:4614)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:3190)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:694)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:789)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:31)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:247)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at socket.android.ClientActivity$ClientThread.run(ClientActivity.java:100)
09-10 18:48:48.502: ERROR/ClientActivity(455):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wat to access widgets from another thread the standard way is to use `Handler`

[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) you can find an example how to use `Handler`